# Not able to catch my event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 2 questions about the events with the DOM.

I would like to trigger an event on the DOM, i wrote this code:

```
window.homeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#home-container'),

    initialize : function() {
       this.template = _.template($('#home-template').html());
       this.render();
    },

    events: {
      "click a.fb_connect": 'fetch_user'
    },

    fetch_user: function(){
        console.log("Fetch requested...");
    },

    render : function() {
        this.delegateEvents();
        var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
        return this;
    }

});
```

When i click my link `<a class="fb_connect" href="#"><img src="img/fb-connect.png" alt="fb-connect" /></a>` nothing happend... I don't know why, any idea ?

Another question, i heard about the "custom events", what i want to do here is to trigger an event about my facebook login, so in my example (which doesn't works), i call my event at the click on the link, but i should call the event in the facebook callback to be sure i got the datas, the problem is, the facebook callback is not a DOM event, so i have no idea how trigger it, is there a way with these "custom event" to do this kind of thing ?

Thanks for your help !

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ludoblues/japNK/3/

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No nothing happend, not even an error...

Comment: is the anchor tag part of the template?

Comment: I just gave a link to a jsfiddle to see the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/ludoblues/japNK/3/.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your link is not part of the element defined by the view.

You have this as your template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="home-template">
            <span><%= id %></span>
            <span><%= username %></span>
            <span><%= facebook_id %></span>
            <span><%= facebook_token %></span>
</script>
```

This does not contain the element to which you're attaching an event.

Attaching events through Backbone's event hash works by using the delegate ability of the `on` method from jQuery, but since it doesn't know (or want to know) about when your template is actually attached the DOM (and therefore accessible), it attaches them to the surrounding element created by Backbone, which, in your case is defined by `el : $('#home-container')`

So when Backbone attaches the events, it uses:

```
this.$el.on("click", "a.fb_connect", this.fetch_user);
```

Where `this.$el` is the jQuery wrapped `el` provided (or the `el` generated from the combination of `tagName`, `className`, and `id`).

Since `<a class="fb_connect"...></a>` is not a child of `<div id="home-container>` the click event never gets fired because jQuery is only listening for click events on anchor tags with the class `fb_connect` that are children of `div#home-container`.

If you change your template to:

```
<script type="text/template" id="home-template">
            <span><%= id %></span>
            <span><%= username %></span>
            <span><%= facebook_id %></span>
            <span><%= facebook_token %></span>
            <a href="#" class="fb_connect">OK !</a>​
</script>
```

It works. (Confirmed in the fiddle).

Here's the [documentation for `.on` from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which will help explain this in better detail.

And an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwjY9/)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807149/backbone-js-simple-view-event-not-firing); have you waited for the DOM to be ready?

For the second one, when you cannot rely on model/collection events in Backbone view, I recommend using a pub/sub library: [this one](https://gist.github.com/661855) have my preferences.

Comment: Ok i'll have a look on your library.

Yes i launch the code like this: `$(document).ready(function(){
  App.home();
});`

Comment: Why not use the events aggregator in Backbone? You don't need a separate pub/sub library; it's included.

Comment: The aggregator was designed to work when objects know each other (ie. the view knows the model/collection to listen to). So you can't use as is, could you?